# how do i call the overloaded operator function of a base class into that of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, operator-overloading

```
class Vehicle{
long Number;
int Year;
char *Make,*Model,*BodyStyle,*Color;
float Cost;
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& stream,const Vehicle& v);

class TruckVehicle:public Vehicle{
int Passengers;
long Mileage,GrossWeight,TempGross;
char *PoweredBy;

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& stream,const TruckVehicle& t )
```

in the above code ..how do i call the overloaded << of the base class to the << function of derived class??
replies will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and cleanest way to do this is:-

```
class Base
{
  public:
      virtual ostream& put(ostream& s) const = 0;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const Base& r)
{
    return r.put(s);
}

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
      ostream& put(ostream& s) const;
};

void f(const Base b, Derived d)
{
    cout << b << d;
}
```

i.e put() is a virtual function that ensures that the right output operation is used in <<.

Comment: friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& stream,const TruckVehicle& t )
    {
       // const Vehicle & v(t);
        
        
        
        stream << static_cast<const Vehicle &>(t);
        stream << "Number :" << t.Number << endl;
        
        
     
I tried doing this but it says Number is a private member of Vehicle class.Do you suggest anything for this?

Comment: `virtual ostream& put(ostream& s) const = 0;` and then `const Base b`?